# Include external <script> and prevent loading jQuery multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to include a script from an external site into my site.

```
<script src='http://widgets.something.de/clientidblablabla?parameters=2324' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Too bad, that with that script they also include jQuery 1.4.1. As I am using jQuery 1.8.3 so far some of my scripts break.

Is there a way to prevent loading an external jQuery file? I could for example use the url `http://widgets.something.de/resources/jquery-1.4.1.js` and block it?

Although this script is quite huge, but only needed on desktop computers. How can I implement this `<script src="">` tag into an `if($(window).width() > 768px) { // fire script };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply use another alias to load your jquery and let the plugin to use the common alias `$`.

The usually is to load all plugins and use them when you need. So `if($(window).width() > 768) { // fire script }` sounds well. Another way is using jQuery `getScript()` method, which allows you to load scripts asynchronously:

```
(function(j){

    if( $(window).width() > 768 ){
        j.getScript('http://widgets.something.de/clientidblablabla?parameters=2324', function(){
            // script loaded, you can play with it from here
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**Edit:**

I made an example ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/yptLha3s/)) to explain it better.

```
(function(j213){

    // right now j213 and $ are aliases of the same version (2.1.3)
    j213('body').append( 'j213 = ' + j213().jquery + '<br/>' );
    $('body').append( '$ = ' + $().jquery + '<br/>' );

    j213.getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js', function(){

        // once another version of jQuery has been loaded, $ becomes an alias for 1.4.1 while j213 still holds for 2.1.3
        $('body').append( '$ = ' + $().jquery + '<br />' );    

        // you can also remove an alias
        delete $; // or $ = undefined; 
                  // or $ = null;
                  // or $ = 'whatever you want';

        j213('body').append(typeof($) + '<br />'); // returns undefined

        // or assign a new one easily
        $ = jQuery; // $ is now 1.4.1 - the last jQuery loaded
        $('body').append( '$ = ' + $().jquery + '<br />' );

        $ = j213; // $ is now 2.1.3
        $('body').append( '$ = ' + j213().jquery + '<br />' );

    });


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Please tell me what i am missing... if you load both jQuery 1.4.1 and jQuery 1.8.1, which one is in the jQuery variable that you are passing into your function?

Comment: In this case, to match OP request, `$` is already assigned by the plugin, while we assign `j` to our own jQuery. You can also (un)set any jQuery alias using the `$.noConflict()` method ([see doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)).

Comment: The call to `$.noConflict()` is 100% neccessary for your code to work. If `$.noConflict()` is not called, the `$` inside the function will also point to 1.8.3

Comment: I disagree: http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/yptLha3s/. Remember that the last loaded jQuery version persists @marstato

Comment: With that example it is clear to me. However, your first code will not work - which is what i criticized.

Comment: I see what you say, it was just an example, but I'll remove it to clarify the question. Thank to your criticism the answer was improved 

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery 1.4.1 is within the same file as the widget you are loading, i see no way of not loading it. But you can get rid of jQuery 1.4.1 in the browser by first loading that widget, then "removing" the `$` and `jQuery` Variables (`delete $; delete jQuery;`) and **then** loading your jQuery 1.8.3.

You can conditionally load the file using document.write or by loading it via an XHR-Request and passing it to `eval()`

Comment: with that, plugins might hard-code `$`, which could refer to a different version of jq than the plugin was written for...

Comment: the script loads a whole lot of html tags as well, includes a form etc. So I do have to load this script inside my body tag. If its important, I am using wordpress as cms.

Comment: @danavis: Using two jQuery Versions peacefully at the same time is impossible imo, therefore the widget will have to work with 1.8.3 if the TE can't work with 1.4.1; a test will tell, hopefully

If you load the widget within your body, you will have to load jQuery 1.8.3 in the body, too, if you want to overwrite the 1.4.1

Comment: I have to say that you can use as much jquery versions as you want without problems. The way is to assign each framework to a different alias. So you can use `jq141('body').html('hello')` and below `jq183('body').html('byebye')` and both work. See my answer to see it a little more detailed.